# Compile windows service without Visual Studio

Tags: windows, service, msbuild

Is it possible to compile a Windows Service developed in Visual Studio without use the IDE? I need to compile it externally. Could I use MSBuild or other similar tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft Build Tools 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159) are available as a separate download. They comprise a set of build tools without an IDE.